# Terms of conditions for soapui-4.5.1.jar and xmlbeans-2.4.0

Tags: java, web-services, licensing, gnu, soapui

I'm going to use java libraries soapui.jar and xmlbeans.jar from maven repository http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/eviware
What licence they are under?
Can I add them to my web application if it will absolutely free but I will not provide access to my source code and I'm going to spread this application as my own product?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoapUI is licensed under the [GNU Lesser General Public License](http://www.soapui.org/Developers-Corner/soapui-license.html).

XMLBeans is licensed under the [Apache License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0). You can find a nice summary of it [here](http://www.inteist.com/2010/05/how-to-use-apache-2-0-in-commercial-products-explained-in-simple-terms/).

In answer to your question you can add them to your web application if it will be free, you credit the library and provide it with a copy of the license.